# Copy MFC Library to project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc, inno-setup

I am new to C++, and I have made a program on visual studio 2010. I then made an installer for it using [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/iskb.php?vc). When I install it on my computer it runs fine, but when I move it to another computer and install it, an error appears like "mfc100ud.dll" is missing from your computer".

My question is: If I just copy the MFC files into my visual studio project directory, make another installer for it and run it on another computer; will the program work? Or do I have to do something else? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That 'd' in mfc100ud means you have linked to the debug version of MFC. The debug dll is only available with Visual C++ installed. You need to build a release version of your program. And you need to include the VC redistributable package in your installer, or change the runtime and MFC libraries to statically link into your program.

Comment: It did work, i'm getting no errors now but the program won't start for some reason. But that's a different problem entirely. Thanks for your help